# Reduce size of bitmap at run time

Tags: android

I am using bitmap whose size is large. while loading bitmap in memory its giving me outofmemoryexception Is there any way to do reduce the size without change in height and width and quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through these lessons for displaying bitmaps efficiently:  http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code 
to Reduce the Size of the image you need to cut down the  diminssion of the image

```
public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, width, height,
            matrix, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will give you screen resolution at run time.

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
deviceHeightPix = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
deviceWidthPix = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

and from that you can pass those height and width or resolution as you want in following function. This function will return you a sample size created from original one.
And it will not reduce any quality.
For example, you have screen size of 480 * 800 (Normal and Medium Density)
And your image has size 1500*2000, so first get your screen size,
pass to following function, it will return back 480*800 resolution image without reducing its quality.

```
public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    Log.d("Home", "Image Resizer -> ReqHieght : " + reqHeight);
    Log.d("Home", "Image Resizer -> ReqWidth  : " + reqWidth);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);
    Log.d("Home", "Image Resizer -> Samplesize:" + options.inSampleSize);
    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

To use above function,

`Bitmap bitmap = DecodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),R.drawable.home_screen,480,800);`

Benefit of using this function is that, you don't need to create `TWO` objects of `Bitmap`.
First object holds `decoded` image, and second object use that first object to `scale` it.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
 * 
 * @param file
 * @param requiredSize
 * @return
 */
public static Bitmap decodeFile(File file, int requiredSize) {
    try {

        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, o);

        // The new size we want to scale to

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < requiredSize
                    || height_tmp / 2 < requiredSize)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file),
                null, o2);

        return bmp;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } finally {
    }
    return null;
}
```